# 何故.NET Framework(CLR)は仮想スタックマシンを採用したのでしょうか？

Tags: .net

特にCLRは構造体のようなコピーコストの高い機能がありますが、スタックマシンは一般にコピー回数が増えがちかと思います。
今でこそJITコンパイラが成熟したおかげでこのあたりの技術選択がそこまでクリティカルにはならないと思いますが、コピーコストを抑える意味でもレジスタマシンを採用したほうが自然に思えました。
実際に、Luaは確か5.0からコピーコストを嫌ってレジスタマシンに再実装したと記憶しています(LuaはTagged Poinetrのようなハックを嫌ったため即値でさえヘッダを含むとか(うろ覚え))。
MSや開発者の言質があれば最高ですが、推測でも大変ありがたいのでご意見いただければと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C#コンパイラーチームのEric Lippertさんが[Why have a stack?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/11/28/why-have-a-stack/)にて次のように発言されていました。

> There are several reasons, but again, it primarily comes down to lowering costs. Stack machines are very easy to understand, they are very easy to write a compiler front-end for, they are easy to build interpreters for, they are easy to build jitters for, and they provide a concise abstraction for the common case. The common case is that the result of any particular operation is only going to be of interest for a brief period.

様々なコストを加味してのようです。CLRはC#やVBだけでなく、C++/CLIやJ#やF#、PowerShellなど多くの言語からIL生成されることも意識しているようです。またJITコンパイラが解析しやすいという点も含まれているようです。

---

詳しくないのですが、レジスタマシンでは構造体を保持できないのでは…その場合、Javaのようにすべて参照型としてGCで管理する必要がありませんか？ 勘違いならすみません。

Comment: おっと、コメントってEnterで受け付けられてしまうんですね…申し訳ないです…。改めてありがとうございます。おかげで納得できました。レジスタマシンで構造体の扱いですが、正直どこまでをレジスタマシンというのかがアレですが、個人的に問題視していたのがコピーコストですので、レジスタアクセスさえ出来れば問題ないと考えておりました。であれば構造体サイズさえ既知であれば実装は可能かな、と(ほとんどスタックマシンとレジスタマシンのハイブリッドみたいな形になりそうですが)。

Comment: @Anonymouse さん、実は仮想マシンにおけるコピーコストの意味がよくわかりませんでした。ネイティブコードを生成した際にコピーが発生するかどうかではありませんか？ また、参照型で発生するGC管理コストを嫌って値型・構造体なので、コピーコストが嫌なのであればGC管理コストをかけて参照型にするまでの話です。